# Concatenation constant and dynamic field in SQL LOADER

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I am trying to concatenate 2 fields into a single field in CTL file and then load the data through SQL loader.

EXAMPLE:

```
TABLE - "EMPINFO" where the fields are     
(name,mobile_no,service,data_insert_time).
```

The data given is `(Jack,005492906405,IT)`

But while loading data into the table I need to concatenate the 2 fields (one is constant and another is date) for the data_insert_time field of the table.

So data_insert_time column should be like **`EMPLOYEE-20200304`** `(EMPLOYEE-SYSTEMDATE)` for every data.

`EMPLOYEE` is constant for every data

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying that you *can't* do it in SQL*Loader, but - why bother? Set `data_insert_time` column's **default value**, e.g.

```
SQL> create table empinfo
  2    (name       varchar2(20),
  3     mobile_no  varchar2(20),
  4     service    varchar2(20),
  5     --
  6     data_insert_time varchar2(20) default 'EMPLOYEE-' || to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd')
  7    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into empinfo (name) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from empinfo;

NAME                 MOBILE_NO            SERVICE              DATA_INSERT_TIME
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Littlefoot                                                     EMPLOYEE-20210319

SQL>
```

In SQL*Loader, you'd load all columns except `data_insert_time`.

---

If it *must* be SQL*Loader, then:

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table empinfo
  2    (name       varchar2(20),
  3     mobile_no  varchar2(20),
  4     service    varchar2(20),
  5     --
  6     data_insert_time varchar2(20)
  7    );

Table created.
```

Control file:

```
load data 
infile *
replace
into table empinfo
fields terminated by "," 
trailing nullcols
(
name,
mobile_no,
service,
data_insert_time "'EMPLOYEE-' || to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd')"
)

begindata
Littlefoot,12345678,IT
Jack,005492906405,IT
```

Testing:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@orcl control=test33.ctl log=test33.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Pet O×u 19 07:54:12 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

SQL> set linesize 100
SQL> select * from empinfo;

NAME                 MOBILE_NO            SERVICE              DATA_INSERT_TIME
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Littlefoot           12345678             IT                   EMPLOYEE-20210319
Jack                 005492906405         IT                   EMPLOYEE-20210319

SQL>
```

---

If you meant to actually load employee's name (not `EMPLOYEE` string itself), then modify control file to

```
data_insert_time ":name ||'-'|| to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd')"
```

and the result is

```
NAME                 MOBILE_NO            SERVICE              DATA_INSERT_TIME
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Littlefoot           12345678             IT                   Littlefoot-20210319
Jack                 005492906405         IT                   Jack-20210319
```